# Draw Underline Under Navbar Link

Tags: html, css

[image]

Would like to have that green underline appear BELOW the links. This is my CSS and HTML for this currently:

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item {% if nbar == 'about' %}active{% endif %}">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'about' %}" id="navlink">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {% if nbar == 'login' %}active{% endif %}">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'login' %}" id="navlink">Log In</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    position: relative;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #4EBA6F;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on the after. Note you need to add `position: relative;` on `.nav-item`

```
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}

.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #4EBA6F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple idea with a `linear-gradient` as background:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background:#8563d9;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:#fff;
}

.active {
  background:linear-gradient(#4EBA6F,#4EBA6F) bottom/100% 4px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#" id="navlink">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="active" href="#" id="navlink">Log In</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```